# HTML Comments inside Opening Tag of the Element

Tags: html, tags, comments

When I try this

```
<option disabled = "disabled" <!-- Used to disable any particular option -->
        selected = "selected" <!-- Used to pre-select any particular option -->
        label = "string"      <!-- Used to provide a short version of the content in the option --> 
        value = "value">      <!-- The actual value that will be send to the server. If omitted the content between the option opening and closing tags will be send. -->

Option 1
</option>
```

I am trying to comment the attributes and values inside the openning tag of the element. However this does not work as browsers (tested on IE9, FF4.01, GG11, AF5 and Opera11) treat everything followed after the disabled="disabled" as either comment or content.

Are HTMl Comments not allowed inside the opening tag of elements?

Comment: As pointed out by David, you can't put comments inside another tag. Besides, you shouldn't need to comment html tags, as they are self-describing. There's not an algorithm you have to explain to someone reading the code. So they are kind of redundant and pointless.

Comment: The reason someone would want a comment inside a tag would be not that they want to document what's happening, but they might want to disable an attribute during development without deleting it.

Comment: There is a very serious usecase for nested comments that is often overlooked. You cannot comment out a a block of code containing a block comment inside of it without stripping the comments inside that block. There is no reason for comments not to nest other than compatibility issues, since in essence, it is just a "bracket matching" algorithm that strips away everything inside the brackets. It will make the comment removal algorithm more expensive(it can't simply use regex anymore, it has to parse each comment now), but the payoff is that comments are now not disruptive to future comments.

Comment: My proposal is to use `<noscript class="comment">comment</noscript>` which does not have limitation of `<!-- -->` and then before the document gets to parsing it, have javascript just set it's outerHTML to an empty string. noscript is preferred because it is the only standard tag other than script that is meaningless enough for this to make sense with.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Workarounds for comments inside HTML tags

HTML does not allow you to use `<!--` and `-->` to mark comments inside a tag. However there are workarounds for the main use cases.

### To add a comment within an HTML tag

You can just make up an attribute name that you use just to comment to yourself. For example:

```
<div comment="Name and Id">
   ... 
</div>
```

The major downside is that these comments will not be stripped out during minifying, so:

- it will take up space in your final HTML document served to the user
- if the user clicks `View source` they will be able to read your comments

### To temporarily disable an attribute

Just rename the attribute with a prefix that you decide to use to indicate temporary disabling. For example, to disable an attribute called `option`, you might choose to do this:

```
<div option="big">
   ... 
</div>
```

becomes

```
<div DISABLED-option="big">
   ... 
</div>
```

Obviously don't do this if you actually might need a real attribute called `disabled-option`.

### To temporarily disable a class or style

Since there is no error message if you use a class or style that doesn't exist, you can do this to disable a class or style:

For example, to disable a class called `tall` while preserving a class called `highlighted`:

```
<div class="highlighted tall">
   ... 
</div>
```

becomes

```
<div class="highlighted DISABLED-tall">
   ... 
</div>
```

Similarly, to disable the `color` style while preserving the `font-weight` style:

```
<div style="font-weight:700; color:red;">
   ...
</div>
```

becomes

```
<div style="font-weight:700; DISABLED-color:red;">
   ...
</div>
```

Again, remember that these won't be stripped out during minifying so they will take up space in the file the end user receives, and will be viewable with `View source`.

Comment: Note that in the `style` attribute you can use `/* … */` CSS comments.
Also, you can to insert linebreaks for easier readability inside tags.

Answer (score 63):

HTML comments are not allowed *inside* tags, start or end, at all.

Comment: I wonder if documentation link can be provided

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags

Answer (score 7):

I have kicked off a standard for structuring HTML comments, called 'HTMLDoc', analogous to JSDoc for Javascript, JavaDoc for Java, etc.

You can read about it here: http://usehtmldoc.surge.sh.

It allows documentation at the tag, attribute and value level.

For your code, it might look something like this:

```
<!--
@tag option
@attribute disabled Used to disable any particular option
@attribute selected Used to pre-select any particular option
@attribute label Used to provide a short version of the content in the option
@attribute value The actual value that will be send to the server. If omitted the content between the option opening and closing tags will be send.
-->

<option disabled = "disabled"
        selected = "selected"
        label = "string"
        value = "value">
Option 1
</option>
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Gogol I admit it’s not a direct answer (since, as was pointed out, HTML doesn’t allow inline comments), but I think this is the next best solution. I think this solution does address the questioners stated need to add comments about specific HTML attributes. Do you disagree?

Comment: @Jonathan fair enough. I actually came to this question looking for a way to place comments inside the element tags lol. I am trying to develop a wysiwyg editor plugin that would allow protecting code inside the elements (e.g. allow <div <?php echo "test"?> id="something">abc</div> to be edited in tinymce/ckeditor. The protected plugins do not work for these cases), so for my case.. this answer does not apply atall :).. For others it might apply.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project @Gogol

Answer (score 5):

No.
According to [HTML comment tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp) those comments are tags like any other HTML-tag and thus can not be 
placed inside start or end tags.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot use comments inside HTML tags, but we can use comments after or before HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

###### You can strikethrough the attributes to disable them and also comment out in quotes.

##### Ex.:

```
<option 
  disabled = "disabled" "--Used to disable any particular option"
  selected = "selected" "--Used to pre-select any particular option"
  label    = "string"   "--Used to provide a short version of the content in the option"

  "--You can erase the attribute to disable it:"
  *value = "value"
  -class = "myOptions"
  
  "--Disabling doesn't work with any characters:"
  //id  = "myOption" "--This won't disable it"
  
>Option 1</option>
```

###### The rules you who choose.